# How to write a smart contract for RPi sensor?

Tags: contract-development, raspberry-pi, iot

I have a PC with two nodes running on it, and a Raspberry Pi which also has Geth running. Problem is how to write a smart contract so that sensor to send the measurements to the blockchain periodically, and also is it possible to access this chain from anywhere, given that I know the private key of the account?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A smart contract lives on the blockchain and cannot perform any operations outside of the blockchain world (see also [this excellent article](https://www.multichain.com/blog/2016/04/beware-impossible-smart-contract/)).

You need an oracle for this. An oracle is some piece of software living **outside** the blockchain and communicates with it through some API (e.g. [web3](https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py) or [ethjsonrpc](https://github.com/ConsenSys/ethjsonrpc)).

So in your case you should write a small script (I prefer python for those kind of things) which fetches the sensor data and writes it on the blockchain e.g. by calling a smart contract function. If you just need to store a simple integer value (Solidity doesn't support floating point numbers, so perhaps you need to modify the sensor data accordingly) the following smart contract could help you:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.10;

contract StoreIntegerValue {
    address owner;
    int sensorData;

    function StoreIntegerValue() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function setSensorData(int _sensorData) {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        sensorData = _sensorData;
    }

    function getSensorData() constant returns (int) {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        return sensorData;
    }
}
```

To store the value just send a transaction calling `setSensorData` and to get the value call `getSensorData`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I’m new to Ethereum, so could you please, explain how to add oracle and how to modify sensor data? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on joffi's answer. I've provided a python program you could use on your RPi to submit data to the StoreIntegerValue contract. Please note that a few things may need to be changed for your particular case.

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
from solc import compile_source
from web3.contract import ConciseContract

#Please replace with you actual web3 provider (for more info: http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html)
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'))

#abi can be generated form the command line with solc or online with Remix IDE
abi = '''
[
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_sensorData",
                "type": "int256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setSensorData",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getSensorData",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "int256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    }
]
'''

#Replace with real deployed contract address
address = Web3.toChecksumAddress("0xeab01dba3ef110d5584f3315f2b3e4a86d04eb94")
StoreIntegerValue = w3.eth.contract(
    address, abi=abi, ContractFactoryClass=ConciseContract)

#Replace with real account address for raspi
raspi = 0x907c1a1c053ac1d01bda773b9a36b8ffd00c1cc4

#Example function to submit data to the block chain
def submitSensorData(data):
    #note that data must be an integer,
    StoreIntegerValue.setSensorData(int(data), transact={'from': raspi})

#For more info about using Python to interact with the blockchain, checkout the web3.py documentation http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but could you clarify some points: what is abi? how to know the web3 provider? and does this script send data to contract periodically or by request? Again thank you very much, it helped me a lot